# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Bluetooth Headset No Microphone

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone, headset

i have a pair of Corsair HS70 headphones, which I cannot seem to be able to set up correctly in my ubuntu machine. I can pair them properly and get the sound to work, however when I try to select as sound input the headset's mic, the headset disconnects. I have tried pairing with bluetooth audio manager, but the issues still persist(and bluetooth audio manager, tries to send a crash report sometimes). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the Corsair site *Our headsets are not supported on Linux. The only headsets we manufacture that would work would be ones with 3.5mm headphone jacks but that still relies on your onboard audio or audio card supporting Linux.

[https://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=190903#:~:text=Our%20headsets%20are%20not%20supported,or%20audio%20card%20supporting%20Linux](https://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=190903#:%7E:text=Our%20headsets%20are%20not%20supported,or%20audio%20card%20supporting%20Linux).

Looks like this is not going to happen with these.